# Clarification on Price and Quantity fields of standard Asset object

Tags: standard-objects

Salesforce documentation of the standard `Asset` object fields defines `Price` as, "Amount the customer paid for the asset."  It defines `Quantity` as, "The number of assets purchased.".

It's not entirely clear to me whether the overall value of the `Asset` object is just the `Price` field, or the result of multiplying `Price` by `Quantity`.

Can someone point to documentation or some Salesforce workflow that clearly defines which interpretation is correct?  I'm trying to create some reports based on Asset value, and need to know whether I should just use `Price`, or create a custom field that is `Price * Value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard wording on every reference I could think to check:

> Price paid for this asset.

This suggests that the price is representative of the total cost of the asset, not a unit price. The reasoning behind this is the usage of the word asset in the English language: "His quick wits is his best asset" or "Would you call those one hundred computers an asset?" While an asset might represent a singular item (a group of one), it more commonly represents a collection of items grouped together into a single property.

**Edit:** I think this wording may be intentionally vague, so consistency is your best friend. There's no interaction between opportunities and assets, for example, so there's really no need to make a distinction, except to make the same decision consistently within an organization.

Comment: I'm working on a package that will be used by multiple organizations, and was hopeful that there would be "the one true way" that I should follow.  I agree with your interpretation, but would like something to point to that justifies our design decision.  The definition of Quantity (quoted in original question) refers to "assets" (plural).  I'd be happier with something like, "The number of items comprising this asset."

Comment: IMHO, I'd recommend that you create a custom field called "Unit Price" or some such that explicitly defines its cost as per-unit, and leave Price as a "total value", since that is probably the most practical version of the definition.

Comment: Hopefully someone at salesforce.com will see this and have some clarifications made. I've never thought about that field in particular.

Answer (score -1):

In below, some implementation techniques and best practices are provided
http://appexchange.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_assets_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: That PDF doesn't make any references to Price.  If there is a section that adds clarity, please quote it in your answer.